# decrease time complexity of loops

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm trying to make an array an increasing array , if an element at i+1 is less or equal to element at i, add an int n to that element several times  till it becomes more than than element at i so continue till the last element and print moves needed for entire process . I'm using for and while loop it is working just fine but for some cases it takes too much time. any advice to reduce time complexity and if it is possibe can you give me some info about it(btw I'm newbie)

```
int move=0;
for(int i=0;i<list.length-1;i++)
{
  while(list[i+1]<=list[i])
  {
    list[i+1]+=n;
    move++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider subtraction instead of a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, without lots (possibly millions) of sums in some cases.

```
int move=0;
for(int i=0;i<list.length-1;i++)
{
    if (list[i+1]<=list[i]) {
        int steps = (int)((list[i]-list[i+1])/n) + 1;
        list[i+1] += steps*n;
        move += steps;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should do it this way:

```
int move=0;
for(int i=0;i<list.length-1;i++)
{
  if(list[i+1]<=list[i])
  {
    int toAdd = (int) Math.ceil( (list[i]-list[i+1]) / n );
    list[i+1]+= n * toAdd;
    move++;
  }
}
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: giving this error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Comment: Yeah sorry i forgot the (int) in the first line of the if clause.

Comment: And you don't count `move` as it is done in question, each addition of `n` is a move. Also your code is incorrect: in case of `list[i] == list[i+1]` the line `list[i+1]+= n * toAdd` would add 0 and after exiting if block the condition `(list[i+1]<=list[i])` would still return true.